# Filter result after an unwind

Tags: mongodb

I've got an aggregation with an unwind :

```
{
        $unwind: { "path":"$contributions", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}
    },
```

Output :

```
contributions" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b4e0636d3befc00155ffb8e"),     
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2018-07-17T15:07:34.172+0000"), 
    "validationDate" : ISODate("2018-07-17T15:07:42.008+0000"),     
}, 
contributions" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b4e0636d3befc00155ffb8e"),     
    "rejectionDate" : ISODate("2018-07-17T15:07:34.172+0000"), 
    "validationDate" : ISODate("2018-07-17T15:07:42.008+0000"),     
},
```

Now I want to filter this result to show only result that doesn't have a rejectionDate. So in this example, it should show only one result.

I try to add a filter :

```
$filter: {
            input: `$contributions`, as: 'item',
            cond: { $and: [
              { $not: '$$item.rejectionDate' },
              ...dateRangeFilterHelper('$$item.contributionDate', period)
            ] }
          }
```

But it doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

instead of $not you can use $exists operator. you might get the desired output. Also if you can post the sample dataset and desired output then it will help to write the complete query.

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "contributions":{
                $filter:{
                    "input":"$contributions",
                    "as":"contribution",
                    "cond":{
                        $eq:["$$contribution.rejectionDate", undefined]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7275c4eb1b7fdde7ea09e8"),
    "contributions" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b4e0636d3befc00155ffb8e"),
            "creationDate" : ISODate("2018-07-17T15:07:34.172Z"),
            "validationDate" : ISODate("2018-07-17T15:07:42.008Z")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b4e0636d3befc00155ffb8e"),
            "rejectionDate" : ISODate("2018-07-17T15:07:34.172Z"),
            "validationDate" : ISODate("2018-07-17T15:07:42.008Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7275c4eb1b7fdde7ea09e8"),
    "contributions" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b4e0636d3befc00155ffb8e"),
            "creationDate" : ISODate("2018-07-17T15:07:34.172Z"),
            "validationDate" : ISODate("2018-07-17T15:07:42.008Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it not simplier to do just a match :
  {
   $match: { 
      'fundraisings.creationDate' : {
            $gt: ISODate("2017-12-21T00:00:00Z")
      }
   }
  },

Comment: ```fundraisings``` is an array?